# identifier error in java code for wallet

Tags: java

I'm getting an "identifier expected" error for the following code for comparing 2 wallets and printing each pair of banknotes. Thanks for your help:

```
public void printBankNotePairs(Wallet other)
{
    StringBuffer myBuffer = new StringBuffer("Pair: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 + i; j < other.length; j++)
        {
            **if( this.contents[i] == other.[j]){** 
                myBuffer.append(" " + contents[i]) );
                i++;

            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println(myBuffer.toString());

}
```

Comment: `other.[j]` ? What is that `.`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to complete the expression `other.[j]` in the line

```
if( this.contents[i] == other.[j]) {
```

I guess it is expected to be

```
other.contents[j]
```

Comment: @anonymous I don't think so, since the type of `other` is `Wallet`.

Comment: Oh, then the for loop `other.length` is wrong. I looked at that and didn't notice `other` is of type `Wallet`

Comment: @anonymous not necessarily. `Wallet` can have a field named `length`. Of course it entirely depends on how his class is implemented.